# TableView is not reloading data while pushing a controller and pop it back?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am making a UITableView by inheriting UITableViewControll as below

```
 @interface addAlarm : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource>
```

then I have populating some data in its cells from delegate, as below

```
  if (indexPath.row == 0) {    
        AlarmProjectAppDelegate *delegate = (AlarmProjectAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSString *cellValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name"];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    return cell;
```

then I go to other controller as

```
              Name *ob = [[Name alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:ob animated:YES];

        [ob release];
        ob = nil;
```

as There will be a back button and as I do click that it will be poped and come back on current Class "addAlarm"

but I saw that when it come back, then below method is not being called not even viewDidLoad, so table is refreshing it's data,

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I used
          [self.tableView reloadData];
in viewWillApear, but it won't work and won't call above method

what should I do to solve this problem, if you are not able to understand the question, you may ask again to me in comments,

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you define self.tableView.datasource = self and self.tableView.delegate = self?

Comment: Also, is data display when you launch app ? That is one cell with "Name" as title ?

Comment: It is not the first screen, and I haven't given datasource as self, let me do it

Comment: [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
 [self.tableView setDataSource:self]; did this, but no use :-(

Comment: Is it displaying tableview row before you navigate to another view ? I just want to make sure whether you datasource methods are calling first time or not.

Comment: I am calling datasource in ViewDidLoad, and it is show data at first, but not showing updated data when you come back from other view, cz it is not loading the class again, not even tableView

Comment: what you meant by calling datasource in ViewDidLoad?

Comment: [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
 [self.tableView setDataSource:self]; these two lines in viewDidLoad method

Comment: @Veer `viewDidLoad` will not be called when you come back. `viewWillAppear:` will be and so will `viewDidAppear:` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to you are passing name value in dealloc method. So it is called after viewWillAppear of another view. So that is why your tableview is not being reloaded.

Try to send value in viewWillDisappear method.

Comment: `UITableViewController` already conforms to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols. So both statements are redundant.

Comment: Here is another issue, that Dealloc of Name is being called after ViewWillAppear of addAlarm, what is happening here?

Comment: I have asked another question of stack regarding this behaviour, let me give u link

Comment: see this link, it is also my question and I am assigning value to delegate.name in Name dealloc method, but this method is being called after viewWillApear of addAlarm,